# Moving a forum from development to production

Tags: forum

I've been working on a forum locally and I'm wanting to move it to the live server. I've exported all the db tables and then imported into the live site and added a row to the modules table.

I can see the forum module control panel OK, but when I visit the URL for the forum on the live site, I get a 404. So it seems like I've missed something that needs bringing over. Anyone know what that might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this once. Needed to have the following in my config:

```
$config['forum_is_installed'] = 'y';
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. :)

Comment: Been so long since I actually installed a forum, I forgot about that one!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the forum through a regular template? If so, have you synced the templates on the live site? What about .htaccess? If you're using the "exclude" method you might need to add your forum template (group) there (again, if running through a regular template).